# Battery doesn't charge on high CPU load

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, battery

When my CPU load rises the battery stop working I don't know why

i.e If I start playing a game such as counter strike source the battery won't change unless I minimize the window which brings the load down.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Note: sometimes when flash lags for a sec it shows discharging and charging again also due to high CPU load.

My laptop is a Sony VAIO F series 127FD model.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the PSU can't supply enough power to do both things at once - powering the CPU has a higher priority than charging the battery.

Comment: Or because both generate heat so to keep cool, the battery charger shuts off.

Comment: I am sorry but what you are saying doesn't make since, I am losing battery and not charging so if I keep playing the game the battery will drain and the computer will shut down so thats not my case 

Thanks for the help If you have any other suggestion please let me know

Comment: @bhappy Are you sure the "power brick" is receiving enough power?